# Exception: Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial) in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

My project is location based. It fetch location at every 30 sec. But app is showing following error when it gets install in iphone device:

[image]

```
Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x000000018c3a1014 in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x000000018c46b334 in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x000000018c3159c4 in abort ()
#3  0x000000018bde11b0 in abort_message ()
#4  0x000000018bdfac04 in default_terminate_handler() ()
#5  0x000000018be08820 in _objc_terminate() ()
#6  0x000000018bdf75d4 in std::__terminate(void (*)()) ()
#7  0x000000018bdf71a8 in __cxa_rethrow ()
#8  0x000000018be086f8 in objc_exception_rethrow ()
#9  0x000000018d282e00 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#10 0x000000018ecec074 in GSEventRunModal ()
#11 0x000000019353b130 in UIApplicationMain ()
#12 0x0000000100172964 in main at /Users/apple/Desktop/Project/New_Effy_Checkout/EffyIOS/effyIos/AppDelegate.swift:22
#13 0x000000018c29159c in start ()

Please suggest solution if any.
```

Comment: This could be a crash because you are doing something in a different queue (meaning in the background).... do you have some tasks, which are not running in the main queue?

Comment: @ AlexWoe89 : No i don't have location based code in background thread. But other functionally of app is in background.

Comment: did you already try to debug your AppDelegate during start?

Comment: Yes. I tried it. And in console "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" this error is showing.

Comment: Could you please tell us the procedure on what scenerio app is getting crash?.. On immediate launch ?

Comment: @Kumar KL: Just launch login screen and start location service. It will crash with above specified error. But all location base code is in main thread.